# Cucumber Step Failing on Wrong Step

Tags: javascript, selenium, cucumber

The following step test is failing (on purpose):

```
Then(/^the 150 button has been deselected$/, function () {
    driver.sleep(5000);
    var checboxValue = driver.findElement(By.css('#app > div > div > div > div.col-xs-offset-2.col-xs-10 > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(6) > div > label:nth-child(2) > input[type="checkbox"]'))
    checboxValue.isSelected()
      .then((val) => { return assert.equal(val, true) })
  })
```

However, in the command line the above step passes but the following step fails (with the correct/ expected error message):

```
When(/^Date 1 is entered$/, function () {
    var dateInput1 = driver.findElement(By.css('#app > div > div > div > div.col-xs-offset-2.col-xs-10 > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(5) > div > div:nth-child(1) > input'));
    dateInput1.click();
    driver.sleep(8000);
    return dateInput1.sendKeys('2017-07-13');
  })
```

Here's what's coming up in the command line:

```
(tick)Then the 150 button has been deselected # features\step_definitions\task_2.js:23
   × When Date 1 is entered # features\step_definitions\task_2.js:30
       AssertionError: false == true
           + expected - actual

           -false
           +true
```

What's happening here? To me, the 'Then' step should have failed and the 'When' step should've been blue with a - in the cmd line (ie. isn't reached as the previous step failed).

Thanks

Comment: what npm modules are you using?

Comment: "assert": "^1.4.1", "cucumber": "^3.0.0", "phantomjs": "^2.1.7", "selenium-webdriver": "^3.5.0"

Comment: Those are some of the relevant modules I'm using. I think that's what you were requesting?

Comment: Try replacing `return assert.equal(val, true)` with `assert.equal(val, true)` and see if that helps

Comment: Same result. Throws error in When step still.

Comment: Try using this package instead https://github.com/djungowski/cucumber-assert. I am pretty sure it has to do something with the way of using it.

Comment: Thanks. Will try that and get back to you :)

Comment: Thanks. That seems to have solved it. Now getting 
× Then the 150 button has been deselected # features\step_definitions\task_2.js:24
       Error: false == true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this package instead github.com/djungowski/cucumber-assert. I am pretty sure it has to do something with the way of using it.

```
var assert = require('cucumber-assert');

module.exports = function() {

    this.Given(/^the field E-Mail is filled with "([^"]*)"/, function (email, callback) {
        var fieldValue = this.getFieldValue('#password');
        assert.equal(fieldValue, email, 'Expected E-Mail to be ' + email).then(callback, callback);
    });

}
```